# Can coax cables be replaced with a wireless solution?

Tags: television, coaxial-cable

I recently moved my TV to a location (within the same room) with no direct connection to a coax socket. I have been searching the web for ways to make this connection without having to drill holes or pass coax wires across the room.

This is possibly a stupid question but can you think of any solution to have coax "wirelessly"?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there carpet in the room?  There's no wireless solution for coax, so one way or another you're going to have to run wire.

Comment: Just   to clarify. **By coax socket you mean Electrical Outlet**. You will need to use an extension cord or pay to have a new Electrical Outlet installed.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, coax is the signal cable.

Comment: Yes, there are many wireless coax replacement systems on the market. As this then becomes a product search question, it's off-topic.

Comment: @isherwood OP appears to be asking a yes/no question, and possibly some "give me some google words" question.

Comment: Initially, yes. That makes it too broad.

Comment: Dooh.  i had a brain malfunction. *To quote the great Roseanne Roseannadanna, "NEVERMIND"*

Comment: @AlaskaMan Glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: what is the TV using the coax for? that sounds like the 90s, when analog cable was distributed physically.

Comment: @dandavis  Coaxial cable can transmit TV content from a cable service provider, internet from a from an internet service provider ( wireless is an option ) or over the air broadcast transmissions from a roof top or interior antenna.

Comment: @AlaskaMan: it must be DTV then, the other options don't make any sense for a TV. If it were for a cable box, OP could extend the hdmi or component without moving coax... I was trying to sniff out if a chromecast could help, but without an external ATSC box, it won't, and the new answer covers all that

Comment: I run a coax cable to directly to my Tv from the an outdoor antenna. Perhaps the OP has an outdoors antenna that is wired into a wall box and coax from wall box to TV.  We Need more info from the OP.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable

Answer (score 3):

I only know of two solutions to this problem, and they may or may not work for you depending on a few details

### Run Wire

If you have carpet, there is normally a small gap between the wall and the trim and the tack strip where you can just fit a coax cable or ethernet cable.  This is the trick I always used in apartments since modification to the walls was frowned on.  I've even run coax *under* the carpet across the room.  If you run it under the pad, you can still feel a lump when you step right on it, but it's largely invisible.

If you don't have carpet, a good solution is to get white coax and run it along the baseboard with some tacks or staples.  You can even run it around doorways.  Of course this isn't super-attractive, but it works and is easy to DIY and to un-DIY.

Running wires through the walls, attic, or crawlspace is the *best* way to handle this, but it sounds like you can't do that.

### Send wireless *video*

There isn't a way to send the entire coax signal wirelessly across the room, but there are devices to send a video signal across the room to the TV.  Reading between the lines, that means that your cable box that actually hooks up to the coax will still need to hook up to the coax and have a home on that side of the room.

The wireless devices will take video from the component or HDMI output of the tuner and send it to the TV.  Some will even have a solution to handle the signal from the remote control so you can still point it at the TV instead of the other side of the room.  That means the cable box can be totally hidden, but it still has to live next to the coax cable.

Comment: Just a comment because I'm currently trying to **not** answer (and if someone decides this is a comment that is too much of an answer and deletes it, so be it): In my area, Comcast/Xfinity has some set-top boxes that work over WiFi, though only to their own routers. So if this is "cable TV" (as opposed to coax to an antenna) then it is worth a call to your cable company to find out if they have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be the solution you are looking for: an HDHomerun Prime from Silicon Dust connects to cable and has three tuners in it that are converted to DLNA. Older desktops with Windows Media Center can access it to watch live TV or for home DVR. Some Bluray players and smart TV can also access it natively. It is limited to SD video over 2.4GHz wifi, runs HD over wired Ethernet. However, this is a terribly expensive solution just to have wireless connection in the same room. I use this to feed TV to my mother-in-law's home 300ft away via underground fiberoptic. (with appropriate fiber/ethernet converters on either end. Works OK. I am sure it'd work great in your case but probably too costly a solution vs. running a bit of coax.)

Answer (score 0):

**Flat coaxial cable under thick rug**

I have a similar problem to solve with regards positioning.

But my approach is to find a discrete cable solution, a flat cable that will run under a thick rug.

Some answers to my question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617881/can-coaxial-tv-aerial-cables-be-flat-ribbon-to-go-under-thick-rug-for-tv-opposi/617884

Or a wireless solution, wireless HDMI if possible wculd appeal to me but I'd also need an infrared repeater so that I can point the remote at the TV at the new position, even though the set top box is at the old position.

https://www.howtogeek.com/405463/what-is-wireless-hdmi-and-should-you-use-it/

https://uk.bestreviews.guide/ir-repeaters

No affiliation, referral or benefit to me with the links.